# Accessing Modules using EnvDTE90. Visual Studio Automation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, envdte, visual-studio-automation

I am using EnvDTE Interface for automation. I need to access the modules while debugging. I can access expressions, locals but I am unable to find anything related to modules. I need to access the modules in a particular frame. EnvDTE90 does have module and modules interface but I am unable to access it using any kind of method call.

Comment: The Modules property first became available on the Process3 interface.  My crystal ball says that you just forgot to cast, apply (Process3) to the process reference you got.  If you want a better guess then show your code.

Comment: I got it. Used Process3 to get the modules. I was looking in the wrong place. Thank you @HansPassant